# How to post 1 form and 1 other value coding at same line?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to post 1 form and 1 other value  coding at same line?

Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "...",
    data: $('.form').serialize(), & id = 10, // not work
    success: ....

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "...",
    data: $('.form').serialize()+'&id = 10',
    success: ....

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also send that value separately.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "...",
    data: {form : $('.form').serialize(),id: '10'},
    success: ....

});
```

Comment: data: {form: $('.wrap form').serialize(),id:'10'},

Comment: Thats what i added :).  Seems like a class name change.  But you got the idea.